# Need to find the Second matching value from a range of rows in excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to find the Second matching value from a range of rows. Sample is attached. Table on the right side should be the output. Such as when I select 41110, if there are two 41110, value should be the second one on the list.

Data and Expected result...

[image]

Comment: my advice, if you could sort the File Value column first, then using vlookup to get the first value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use following formula. I make this formula on basis of given data. If your actual data is different then you have to customize the formula as your own.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$10=D2,ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$1)),1))
```

[image]

Note: The formula is an array formula. So, you must press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` after typing formula.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) with sub-function 15 ([SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29)), option 6 (discard errors) with a *k* of 2 (second matching occurance). Force any non-matches into an error state (e.g. `#DIV/0!`).

[image: aggregate_second]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>